# EF Core HasQueryFilter works for only the first value in filter expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filter, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using EF Core HasQueryFilter extension method, which is inside the OnModelCreating method.

I am injecting the user id into the DbContext using a service and then applying the userId to the query filter. For the first time when the OnModelCreating is executed it works fine as expected. But when I change the user and pass a different userId to the DbContext then query filter is not affected as obvious because the OnModelCreating is not called this time.

A little background of the App: It's a core 2.2 API project which authenticates users using the JWT token. I populate the user claims and initialize the injected auth service using the JWT, so for every call to the API the userId can be different hence query filter should work on different userIds.

Example codes below:

```
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;

    public SqlContext(DbContextOptions options, IAuthService authService) : base(options)
    {
        _authService = authService;
    }

    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.ManufacturerId == _authService.ManufacturerId);
    }
}
```

How the DbContext is initialized.

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<TContext>(o =>
            o.UseSqlServer(configuration["Settings:SqlServer:DefaultConnection"],
                b =>
                {
                    b.MigrationsAssembly(configuration["Settings:SqlServer:MigrationAssembly"]);
                    b.CommandTimeout(60);
                    b.EnableRetryOnFailure(2);
                })
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings =>
            {
                warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning);
            }))
            .AddTransient<TContext>();
```

Comment: It should work though - as soon as the filter expression is using a field/property/method from the db context as in the example code. Is this your real code? I mean, the query filter is configured exactly like in the post (and not with custom extension method or external configuration class)?

Comment: I think lifetime of the DbContext is important. modelBuilder is called only on Startup and I don't think that  QueryFilter is hit everyime a user makes request

Comment: @Simonare It doesn't matter how many times `OnModelCreating` is called, as soon as the db context is instantiated (`new`-ed) properly. The scenario is supported, but requires specific filter expression setup.

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes the code is exactly like that. So, when the first user makes the call, the ManufcaturerId is set to 1 and when some other user makes a call then the ManufacturerId is not changed and remains 1 as OnModelCreating is not getting called again. I believe that the query filter is cached when it is created for the first time.

Comment: How can I rebuild the model with new filter for every user request.

Comment: There is no need to rebuild the model. See  the [model query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#model-level-query-filters) example and the text after it: *"Note the use of a DbContext instance level property: TenantId. Model-level filters will use the value from the correct context instance (that is, the context instance that is executing the query)"*. If the code is exactly like that, and your db context constructor is called per request, the filter should work.

Comment: The DbContext constructor does get called for every request. I get the changed values as well but still, the filter doesn't work. I have edited the question to show the example of how I initialize the DbContext.

Comment: @IvanStoev you mean that the DbContext is registered as Transient right?

Comment: The only difference from the documentation example (and my global query filter tests which proved the feature is working) I see is the usage of a db context pool. As [doc says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#limitations-1), *"Avoid using DbContext Pooling if you maintain your own state (for example, private fields) in your derived DbContext class that should not be shared across requests"*. Try replacing `services.AddDbContextPool` with `services.AddDbContext`.

Answer (score 5):

Finally solved it.

As the filter was working, but it was not getting updated once the model was created after first request. The reason was that EF was caching the created model. So, I had to implement the **IModelCacheKeyFactory** in order to capture the different models as per the filters.

```
internal class DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context is SqlContext dynamicContext)
        {
            return (context.GetType(), dynamicContext._roleCategory);
        }
        return context.GetType();
    }
}
```

And attached it to the context like this.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(builder);

        builder.ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory>();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this solution - I'd just realised the model gets cached in my own implementation (where the query filters are actually generated in code for each specific user), so this enabled me to force EF to use a cached-per-user model.